# How to use count and max in the same query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, count, max

I am working on mysql 5.0.41,right now I have a table named table1 with fields id,jobs,team. now I would like to know which team has the most number of jobs.

```
id jobs    team
1  washing  team1
2  cleaning team2
3  building team3
4  driving  team1
.......
```

first I use:

```
select team,count(*) from table1 group by table1.team;
```

then I got records like this:

```
team1 23
team2 45
team3 25
```

Actually I would like to get my final result is:

```
team 45
```

the max number of the count
so here are my question:

1. If I want to get the final result, what's sql query I should use?
2. How do i get it by using a query?

Comment: You could order by count desc and Limit 1

Comment: A search like 'mysql select thing with most things' would surely answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Sort by count, then choose the top record.

```
SELECT team, count(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.team
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select team , max(count(*)) from table1 group by table1.team
```

Comment: "ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function"

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. Code-only answers are frowned-upon and can be deleted on reviews. This is a suggestion for this and future answers. Thanks!